# YouCompleteMe - Path of file

Tags: settings, vim, vim-plugin, vimrc

I would like to know settings that disable showing the path after dash. It is disturbing and not necessary.

I tried to search on google on [**YouCompleteMe**](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe)  doc, but unsuccessful. I have no idea which keywords to use. And also I tried to find in vim

```
:help ycm
```

but also not successful.

I provided an output of auto-completion that shows the paths. Thank you for any ideas.

```
HASH_Accumulate(          f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(HASH_HandleTypeDef *hhash, uint8_t *pInBuffer, uint32_t Size, uint32_t Algorithm) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_hash.c
HASH_CR_ALGO              d /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include/stm32l4s5xx.h - 10444
HAL_ADC_Init(             f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_adc.c
HAL_ADC_Stop(             f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_adc.c
HAL_SD_Abort(             f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(SD_HandleTypeDef *hsd) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_sd.c
HAL_ADC_Start(            f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_adc.c
HAL_DMA_Abort(            f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_dma.c
HAL_SAI_Abort(            f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(SAI_HandleTypeDef *hsai) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_sai.c
HAL_SPI_Abort(            f HAL_StatusTypeDef @@(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi) - /home/machy/git/iotprojectg2/device/core/ST/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_spi.c
```

I wrote this question because google failed me (or I failed google that?).

Comment: Please don't put pictures of text screen. Copy the text from terminal and paste directly into the question. Then highlight the pasted text and format it as code using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks for your feedback. I tried your suggestion but it does not work for me so I used ``` instead.

Comment: It should work. You may need 2 line-breaks before and after the the code to be formatted.